# How can I block some public IPs to access my Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed my Kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS and using ingress gateway to block IPs to access my certain services. Is there a way I can block those public IPs to access my Kubernetes cluster from inside my cluster (say using ingress-gateway) if not, then is there a way to white list certain IPs to access cluster from inside the cluster?
I am already aware that the security group of AWS will be able to do this but I want to implement it from the inside of cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [using Calico on EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html).

> Network policies are similar to AWS security groups in that you can
> create network ingress and egress rules. Instead of assigning
> instances to a security group, you assign network policies to pods
> using pod selectors and labels.